# Prove that for any number $m$ there is always $n$, such that $m - n$ and $m + n$ are prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that for any number $m$, there will always be another number $n$, such that $m - n$ and $m + n$ are both prime numbers. Is this something that is still unsolved or is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Goldbach's conjecture and is still not proved.

Comment: I would say it's a corollary of Goldbach's conjecture but yes, absolutely right.

Comment: Well, I was kind of dumb not to give it a second thought. Guess you're right

Comment: A little elaboration about how this is equivalent to Goldbach's conjecture would be appropriate, especially since the asker did not specify $m$ has to be even.

Comment: The parity of $m$ is irrelevant. If $m-n=p$ and $m+n=q$ then $2m=p+q$

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $m = 0$. Then $n$ can just be any prime, since $-n$ would then also be a prime number, right? I think so, but you might not, in which case a few small $m$ might be the only counterexamples.

Then, without loss of generality, we can limit the inquiry to positive $m$, since the negative $m$ will have the same solutions except for opposite signs.

For $m = 1$, let's choose $n = 4$. Then $m + n = 5$ and $m - n = -3$. That checks out.

For $m = 2$, $n = 5$ might be the only choice.

For $m = 3$, $n = 10$ is one out of many possible choices.